# restricting the types using templates in vc++

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

As far my understanding goes I want to restrict only 2 types int and string for the following class, just like in java template definition with extends.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int>::value || std::is_same<T,string>::value>::type
class ExchangeSort
{
public:
    void bubbleSort(T buffer[], int s);
    void print(T buffer[], int s);
    void bubbleSort(const vector<T>& vec);
};
```

But if I'm instantiating like below

```
ExchangeSort<int>* sortArray = new ExchangeSort<int>;
```

I'm getting errors for the above line ExchangeSort is undefined. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFINAE can be used to conditionally disable function overloads or template specialisations. It makes no sense to try to use it to disable a class template, since class templates cannot be overloaded. You'll be better off using a static assertion:

```
template<typename T>
class ExchangeSort
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<T,int>::value || std::is_same<T,string>::value, "ExchangeSort requires int or string");
public:
  // The rest as before
```

---

As to the errors you were getting, the code didn't make syntactic sense. `enable_if` can only appear where a type is expected. With functions, it's often used to wrap the return type, in which case it's syntactically similar to what you wrote. But with classes, there's no type between `template` and the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way which allows the possibility of adding further specialisations down the line:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//
// Step 1 : polyfill missing c++17 concepts
//
namespace notstd {

    template<class...> struct disjunction : std::false_type { };
    template<class B1> struct disjunction<B1> : B1 { };
    template<class B1, class... Bn>
    struct disjunction<B1, Bn...>
            : std::conditional_t<bool(B1::value), B1, disjunction<Bn...>>  { };
}

//
// Step 2 : create a test to see if a type is in a list
//
namespace detail {

    template<class T, class...Us>
    struct is_one_of : notstd::disjunction< std::is_same<T, Us>... > {};
}

template<class T, class...Us>
static constexpr auto IsOneOf = detail::is_one_of<T, Us...>::value;


//
// Step 3 : declare the default specialisation, but don't define it
//

template<class T, typename Enable = void>
struct ExchangeSort;

//
// Step 4 : define the specialisations we want
//
template<typename T>
class ExchangeSort<T, std::enable_if_t<IsOneOf<T, int, std::string>>>
{
public:
    void bubbleSort(T buffer[], int s);
    void print(T buffer[], int s);
    void bubbleSort(const std::vector<T>& vec);
};


//
// Test
//

int main()
{

    auto esi = ExchangeSort<int>();
    auto ess = ExchangeSort<std::string>();

// won't compile    
//    auto esd = ExchangeSort<double>();

}
```